# Exponential Growth and Decay Problem

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, word-problem

The human ear can withstand 85 dB for 8 hours before permanent hearing damage occurs. Given that the exposure time is halved for every 3 dB increased over 85 dB, find the safe exposure time for:

I) The cabin of a steam locomotive, 100 dB

II)A rock concert 115 dB

I understand that this is a decay question and that you obtain (0.5)^5*8 for the first one but the answer says that you must also multiply this by 60 to obtain an answer in minutes, which makes no sense to me as to how we are not already working in hours.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: Your  $(0.5)^5\times 8=0.25$ so a quarter of an hour, which is $15$ minutes

Comment: The calculation you show gives a result in _hours_.  Apparently, you are being asked to express your answer in _minutes_, so you need to multiply your answer by 60 (minutes/hour).

Comment: You **pretend** that you are being asked for an answer in hours, and compute the *final* answer, in hours.  Then, **after** this computation is complete, you convert the final answer from hours to minutes.

Comment: Thanks guys! Makes sense, thanks a lot!